# How to find child-parent tree from sql table

Tags: mysql, sql, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I have a table `child` where I have below structure:

```
id  child_name  parent_id   parent_name
1   vikas        2           sunny
2   john         3           seema
3   ajay         4           delhi
4   josh         4           main
```

I am trying to find child to parent till parent_name matches to main, then I will stop. I need single query sql if it is possible.

I tried this but it is giving me only one level.

```
SELECT ChildUserType.child_name, 
       ChildUserType.parent_name,       
       ParentUserType.id, 
      ParentUserType.parent_id
FROM groups AS ChildUserType
  LEFT JOIN groups AS ParentUserType 
         ON ChildUserType.id = ParentUserType.parent_id 
where ChildUserType.id='1';
```

Comment: Can you please show what you have tried so far? At SO, we would like to help out on technical problems or the like, we cannot provide code from scratch. Please read our [how to ask guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more details

Comment: i m editing this with my answer.

Comment: i am trying to pass where id = 1,then trying to find all child where id=1.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? [Modern DBMS](http://modern-sql.com/slides) support recursive queries

Comment: i am using mysql .

Comment: You can't do this in a single SQL statement with the limited features of MySQL - it doesn't support recursive queries. You need to process this data in your application in a loop or change your database design (or upgrade to Postgres). For MySQL solutions see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql+hierarchical-data

Comment: can u help me with this sql if possible;

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE find_ancestry(IN id_init int)
 BEGIN
 DECLARE child_id int;
 DECLARE prev_id int;
 SET prev_id = id_init;
 SET child_id=0;
 SELECT parent_id into child_id 
 FROM groups WHERE id=id_init ;
 create TEMPORARY  table IF NOT EXISTS temp_table as (select * from groups where 1=0);
 truncate table temp_table;
 WHILE child_id <> 0 DO
   insert into temp_table select * from groups WHERE id=prev_id;
   SET prev_id = child_id;
   SET child_id=0;
   SELECT parent_id into child_id
   FROM groups WHERE id=prev_id;
 END WHILE;
 select * from temp_table;
 END //
```